# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061)

Tags: connection, sendgrid, confirmation

I use SendgridAPI for send confirmation email to user. i create API_key in sendgrid application (https://app.sendgrid.com) and install its api in my project.

my execute code in c# is like this:

```
public static async Task<bool> Execute(string userEmail, string userName, string plainTextContent, string htmlContent, string subject)
        {
            var apiKey = "SG.E43545453453URY1A.tq8j-fduDHDKONPuf_Gp1W35IkQjI-DzRsAsmgdfdfg5DgEBM";
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Mehran");
            var to = new EmailAddress(userEmail, userName);
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
```

and i call this method. when run application and this method, throw exception below:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SendGrid.Helpers.Reliability.RetryDelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at SendGrid.BaseClient.MakeRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SendGrid.BaseClient.RequestAsync(Method method, String requestBody, String queryParams, String urlPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SendGrid.BaseClient.SendEmailAsync(SendGridMessage msg, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at AnguralToApi.Services.SendGridAPI.Execute(String userEmail, String userName, String plainTextContent, String htmlContent, String subject) in E:\Asp.Net Project\AnguralToApi\AnguralToApi\Services\SendGridAPI.cs:line 19
   at AnguralToApi.Controllers.AccountController.Register(RegisterModelView model) in E:\Asp.Net Project\AnguralToApi\AnguralToApi\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 66
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 91
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:49839
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.1
Postman-Token: 6131aae5-b461-4be5-bc78-3aef28950a5e
```

Do you can help me?!

Answer (score 1):

First off, never place an API key into a public forum or check into source control as this can mean someone could use it spam from your account.

Second, the type of connection error makes me think that you are blocked from connecting to sendgrid from a firewall, anti-virus,etc. Another possibility is that the machine that api.sendgrid.com is resolving to is not correct.